# Function to generate a palindrome

Tags: python, function, palindrome

I have this following that I can't seem to solve correctly.
I have to write a function that takes a positive integer n as an input and checks if it is a palindrome (a number that's the same forward and backward). If it is, I have to return this number. If it isn't, I have to calculate the sum of the original number with the reversed number. This step is repeated until the result is a palindrome. This is the code I have so far:

```
x = input("Enter a positive integer: ")

def generate_palindrome(n):
    if n == n[::-1]:
        return n
    else:
        while n != n[::-1]:
            r = n[::-1]
            int(n) += int(r)
    return n

generate_palindrome(x)
```

Of course this returns an error, since `int(n) += int(r)` is not possible. However, when not using `int`, it adds it as a string and that's also incorrect.

I'm not sure how far I'm off with the solution. How can I implement this correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are close. You just need another variable for the integer version of your string.Then just be clear which holds a string and which holds an integer:

```
def generate_palindrome(n):
    if n == n[::-1]:
        return n
    else:
        while n != n[::-1]:   # n needs to be a string for this to work
            r = int(n[::-1])  # r and s need to be numbers for correct addition
            s = int(n)
            n = str(r + s)    # n needs to still be a string for the next loop iteration
    return n

generate_palindrome("989")
# '989'

generate_palindrome("98")
# '8813200023188'
```

FWIW, I don't know that [this is always guaranteed to return a reasonably sized number for every input](https://www.mathpages.com/home/kmath004/kmath004.htm). For example, I gave up on `generate_palindrome("5798")`.

Comment: Currently, there are no proven base-10 [Lychrel Numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lychrel_number) (although there are many likely candidates). Strictly speaking, `5798` isn't a true candidate, since its sequence of iterations `[5798, 14773, 52514, ...]` converges with the one for the lowest true candidate (i.e. `[196, 887, 1675, 7436, 13783, 52514, ...]`). A few yeras ago, `196` was iterated to a billion digits without finding a palindrome.

Comment: Interesting, thanks @ekhumoro. `5798` was just an unlucky guess on my part. Seems like I am in good company for not knowing if this always produces a palindrome.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! Now that I know the solution it seems so simple but I probalby would've never come up with it.